# Why is this LTO4 Tape-drive not working

Tags: linux, tapedrive, lto-4

```
# modprobe mptsas
# dmesg

[ 4274.796796] scsi target7:0:0: mptsas: ioc1: delete device: fw_channel 0, fw_id 0,  phy 0, sas_addr 0x50050763124b29ac
[ 4274.939579] mptsas 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[ 4280.934531] Fusion MPT SAS Host driver 3.04.12
[ 4280.934552] mptsas 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[ 4280.934692] mptbase: ioc2: Initiating bringup
[ 4281.490183] ioc2: LSISAS1064E B3: Capabilities={Initiator}
[ 4281.490203] mptsas 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[ 4293.555274] scsi8 : ioc2: LSISAS1064E B3, FwRev=011e0000h, Ports=1, MaxQ=277, IRQ=16
[ 4293.574906] mptsas: ioc2: attaching ssp device: fw_channel 0, fw_id 0, phy 0, sas_addr 0x50050763124b29ac
[ 4293.576471] scsi 8:0:0:0: Sequential-Access IBM      ULTRIUM-HH4      B6W1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4293.578549] st 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi tape st0
[ 4293.578550] st 8:0:0:0: st0: try direct i/o: yes (alignment 512 B)
[ 4293.578577] st 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 1


# mt -f /dev/st0 status 

mt -f /dev/st0 status
mt: /dev/st0: rmtopen failed: Input/output error



# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nst0 bs=1024 count=10
dd: opening `/dev/nst0': Input/output error
```

I am running debian squeeze

2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Server is Fujitsu TX140 with Controller Symbios Logic SAS1064ET PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS
Tape+Hardware is new.

Comment: Might help if you specify the error messages in english.

Comment: You are right, done.

Comment: Check `dmesg` _after_ you get the I/O error.

Comment: Right... you may just have a media problem or a hardware problem that offlines the device.

Answer (score 2):

For my SAS and SCSI-attached tape devices, I normally see the following modules loaded when I use MPT Fusion/LSI controllers:

```
[root@Lance ~]# lsmod  | grep mpt
mptctl                 31976  4 
mptspi                 17051  0 
mptscsih               36828  1 mptspi
mptbase                94037  3 mptctl,mptspi,mptscsih
scsi_transport_spi     26151  1 mptspi
```

Or...

```
[root@Doper ~]# lsmod  | grep mpt
mptctl                 74953  4 
mptscsih                2625  0 
mptsas                 26977  1 mptscsih
mptspi                 13521  1 mptscsih
mptscsi                50641  2 mptsas,mptspi
mptbase                78625  4 mptctl,mptsas,mptspi,mptscsi
scsi_mod              146193  9 sg,st,libata,cciss,mptsas,mptspi,mptscsi,usb_storage,sd_mod
```

Look at your setup and see if you have the same set of modules loaded.

Comment: Thanks. The Problem was fixed after using the cleaning Cartridge. Did not thought of that because Hardware is new. Helpful was [IBM Tape Device Drivers Installation and User's Guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ssg1S7002972&aid=1)